# Basic rails joins.. Result is a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join

I'm quite new to rails and making an app that lists albums.
Each album should be loaded with two or three preview tracks from that album.

All I want to do is get the preview_url from the previews table where the album_id is the same as the current album.
In mysql, I would use a left join:

```
SELECT preview_id FROM previews WHERE album_id = '{$sanitized_album_id}'...
```

I'm just not sure how to achieve this in ruby.
I can't find a single example that isn't obsessed with posts and comments, and it just isn't clear enough to click yet.

My album controller method looks like this:

```
def show
  @previews = Preview.where(album_id: @album.id).order(track_number: :asc)
end
```

And my show.html.erb file should loop the results with this (simplified) code:

```
<% @previews.each do |preview| %>
  <iframe src="<%= preview %>"></iframe>
<% end %>
```

Although I see no errors and the right number of previews are loading for each album, the resulting code is nonsense to me.

I expect the preview variable inside the do loop to be something like

```
https://website.com/previews/1984628754234
```

Instead, it looks more like this:

```
#<Preview:0x00007fcc08572c38>
```

I guess this is the database resource or something, but not the actual data I [think I] requested.

All the youtubes and whatnot didn't help me and I've only got a few hairs left...
Any one of you fantastic coders able to spare a moment to show me my stupid mistakes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will load all the attributes of Preview, it internally is performing a `SELECT *`.

```
  @previews = Preview.where(album_id: @album.id)
```

if looping through `@previews` you would need to call `preview.preview_id` on each entry to get the value for that column.

In order to get a query like you showed - `SELECT preview_id` - you could use `Preview.where(album_id: @album.id).select(:preview_id)`. You would still need to call `.preview_id` on each entry in the list, but it wouldn't load additional data.

If you want to make a query but you just want the plain array of `preview_id` values, you can use `Preview.where(album_id: @album.id).pluck(:preview_id)`.

See:

- [select](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-select)
- [pluck](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)

Comment: Thank you for this! I knew it would be something small. When I added the .pluck(:preview_id), it worked perfectly.
I didn't have to change the view at all.

Comment: @Kane just for your understanding, `.pluck(:preview_id)` is the same thing as `.select(:preview_id).map(&:preview_id)`. Glad you figured it out

Answer (score 0):

That's a Preview instance. You probably want a field on Preview like:

```
<iframe src="<%= preview.preview_url %>"></iframe>
```

You can't just load in the model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I didn't have to modify the view code - only adding the pluck part to the controller fixed my issue. Please forgive any confusion my being a noob might have introduced..

Comment: @Kane Two solutions to the same problem. If you *only* care about that field then `pluck` works, but keep in mind that gives you naked values. If you want the model, and all the associated helpers that come with, you need to access the field.

Comment: Thanks. I'm really at the beginning with rails - not even sure how to use helpers yet, but I understand your point and will try to remember it. :)